# Can I pair an iPhone6 running 9.3.5 with an iMac using 10.9.5?

Tags: iphone, imac, bluetooth

I've been trying desperately to pair my iPhone 6 which is running iOS 9.3.5 with my 27 inch iMac (late 2009) running 10.9.5 with no success. I have tried turning Bluetooth on and off on both devices, and was able to get the pairing code to show up each time, however when I click on the computer name the iPhone message says:

"**Connection Unsuccessful- Make sure the computer is turned on and in range**".

or it says:

"**Connection Unsuccessful- "Username iMac" is not supported**"

It should be noted that on the computer the iPhone is showing up in the Bluetooth drop-down menu from the top right. Also, it shows up in the Bluetooth preferences, but goes back and forth from being paired, and not connected.

Comment: What about trying to connect from the Mac side?

Comment: @Brick see last paragraph. 

Comment: Ok. Sorry, didn't read.

Comment: Why are you trying to pair them?

Comment: @Harv   to share audio from the phone to the computer.

Comment: Why not just update?

Comment: @JMY1000 I have dozens of reasons not to update. My question was about whether these two devices are in fact capable of being paired.

Comment: If it's only for a limited time, would creating a bootable volume of a newer version be a reasonable solution to the issue? I personally don't know why the issue is occurring or how to fix it, but there might be a workaround.

Comment: it seems that this model of computer is not compatible with bluetooth 4 - https://eshop.macsales.com/guides/Mac_OS_X_Compatibility

Answer (score -2, accepted):

As stated in [this article](https://eshop.macsales.com/guides/Mac_OS_X_Compatibility), many older Apple machines, and specifically the hardware specified in the question, have no Bluetooth 4 support.

[image]

The information on that site provides links not only to iMacs, but most Apple machines.

Answer (score -1):

It is not supported to pair an iPhone and a Mac via Bluetooth and use the either of one as a Bluetooth speaker/receiver. Both are in simple terms in the wrong [device class](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/assigned-numbers/baseband)

But you could use a third party tool to make your Mac an Airplay receiver. The one solution I found was [AirServer](https://www.airserver.com/Mac). Start this tool on your Mac and it should show up on your iPhone as an Airplay destination.